# What is the best way to add multiple objects to a core data entity?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm working on a unit converter for a school project and would like to use core data. I have a lot of conversion factors for all the different types of conversions (unit, length, temperature, pressure, time, etc). What's the best way to add the conversion factors? I know how to add one object at a time with:

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityName:entity inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

but is there an easier way to do it so I don't have to type 4 lines of code to enter one object?

Thanks

Comment: 4 lines of code ? I would think your entity is a measurement unit say Weight entity that has a number of properties like weightInKG, weightInPounds, weightInOunces, weightInGrams, weightInMilligrams. You'd insert a new entity to get a new Weight entity, then calculate all the different conversion units and set weight.weightInGrams = weight.weightInKG * 1000.0, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question is somewhat vague.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was vague, I'm trying to add all of my conversion factors into core data so a ton of things aren't living in RAM. @Zhang had a good suggestion with having an entity for each conversion type. As I've tried to teach myself core data I've learned how to add objects with the above method, but how do I add multiple objects to one key?

Comment: Usually there would already be math libraries written by others that you use, you don't normally store these information into Core Data as it would be a waste of space. If I was doing this, I would just store each entity using ISO standard units, weight in KG, time in seconds, distance in metres etc), then create a Conversion class that have numerous conversion formulas for each type of conversion. That way only use a value when you need to process it. Do remember to do any calculations with your Core Data datas, you need to first load them into RAM.